# Prediction Machines Word Problem (Conditional Probability?)

Tags: probability, bayesian, binary-data, predictor, conditional

I am new to statistics but had what I think is a pretty simple question:

Prediction machine 1 correctly guesses the outcome of binary (yes/no) events 60.4% of the time.
Prediction machine 2 correctly guesses the outcome of binary (yes/no) events 71.88% of the time.

These machines work independently and have no knowledge of each other.

If we are trying to predict binary event A, and machine 1 and 2 both predict that the outcome will be YES instead of NO, what can we infer the probability of YES is, using ONLY this information?

I would really like to know what the formula for this is, assuming there is one. The answer should be >71.88% right? But obviously it can't be more than 100%. And I'm also curious what happens if the machines disagree with each other, or if you add more machines.

Thank you!

Comment: There is no formula because it depends on how those predictions might be related.  You will need to supply specific details of your situation.

Comment: I don't understand. They can't be independent? Suppose we can't look inside the machines we don't know how they work, but we know they are doing something, and they have track records as I described.

Comment: On what basis are they making their predictions?  If they are using common information, or even information that is not independent, then their predictions are not independent either.